# How to detect that commits are pushable

Tags: mercurial, push, commit

In Git it is easy, because `remote/branch` is pointing to a different commit than `branch`. How to do it with Mercurial?

Comment: Are you looking for `hg outgoing`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Mercurial 2.1, there is also a purely local solution: **phases**. The `draft` phase is probably what you are looking for. For details, refer to:

https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Phases

You may find `hg phase <rev>` and `hg log -r "draft()"` interesting.

Comment: What's the command line call to show all revisions in the `draft` phase?

Comment: Just be aware that if you're interacting with more than one remote, phases won't help. As soon as a changeset is shared, it's marked public, so outgoing is the only way to determine what is missing from another remote.

Answer (score 7):

If you mean seeing what's different between your local repo and the one you're pushing to, try

```
hg outgoing
```

Comment: This, however, does not work if the repository is offline or missing.

Answer (score 2):

There is an [remotebranch extension](https://bitbucket.org/durin42/hg-remotebranches) that will give you a Git-like setup. It tracks the remote heads for the repositories listed in the `[paths]` and exposes them as tags named `<path>/<branch>`. This lets you run

```
$ hg diff -r foo/default
```

to see what has changed since the `default` branch in the `foo` repository. There is also new revset keywords that let you do things like

```
$ hg log -r "not pushed()"
```

to get what

```
$ hg outgoing
```

would do, but *without* any network traffic.

Answer (score 2):

> What's the command line call to show all revisions in the draft phase?

```
hg log --style phases
```

That will display the log + the phase, since [Mercurial 2.7 (2013-08-01)](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/WhatsNew/Archive#Mercurial_2.7_.282013-08-01.29).

Answer (score 1):

I'd just use `hg outgoing` as others are suggesting, but `hg summary` will tell you too.  It may require the `--remote` option to have it check the remote default server.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to select the changesets for further processing, then you can use the `outgoing` [revset predicate](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#revset). This lets you re-implement `hg outgoing` as

```
hg log -r "outgoing()"
```

but the real benefit is that you can use this in other contexts, such as

```
hg strip "outgoing()"
```